# Folders and documents enter rename mode when left-clicked

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer

My computer enters a weird state from time to time, where it enters "rename mode" whenever I left-click a single time on a folder or document in the explorer. The behavior can be seen in this clip where I first left-click on the folder and the two documents, then finally double-click on the folder:

[image: Demonstration of the problem]

The behavior is intermittent. It comes and goes without me knowing why. Also note that the behavior is not limited to explorer.exe (I have seen it in the solution explorer in Visual Studio for instance).

I have a few ideas that are likely wrong:

- Some setting in Windows is getting turned on/off by a key combination, though I have never heard of such a setting and it seems pretty useless.
- A hardware issue in the keyboard is sending some scan code that triggers the behavior when clicking the items, though I have no idea which keyboard key would be used to do this in combination with a mouse click.

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check the F2 button of your keyboard, that's the rename button. Make sure it's not stuck so that it's continuously pressing the key (try another keyboard?)

Also, check the Double-click speed settings of your mouse. It might click twice while you think you click only once.

Comment: Thank you, Windows was definitely receiving F2, although it happened even after my keyboard was disconnected. Pressing F2 made it stop, and if I hold the F2 button down and perform a mouse-click, the behavior is exactly as I experienced.

Answer (score 0):

I’ve been having this problem and it’s super frustrating. I ran a program that maps my key usage to see if my f2 key was being pressed. It didn’t show that it was. But it is. Because I downloaded a program called keyTweak and disabled the f2 key and it fixed my problem. Hope this fixes it for everyone having this problem. When you search this issue everyone tells you to change all sorts of setting that do nothing.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).